# Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix. The linear system $Ax = 4x$ has a unique solution if and only if $A − 4I$ is an invertible matrix. True or False?

Tags: linear-algebra

This is the only question I can't figure out in the section. The answer is True (according to the textbook), but I don't know how to start. I got stuck not knowing what $Ax = 4x$ even means, because usually the questions and examples have $Ax = b$, where $b$ is a constant. 
So it would be helpful if someone could explain that "$4x$" part so I can make some progress on the question.

Thanks.

Comment: You could write it as $Ax=4Ix$, where $I$ is identity matrix.

Comment: $4x$ means $4$ times $x$.  Eg, $4(1,2)=(4,8)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So from $A\boldsymbol{x}=4\boldsymbol{x}=4I\boldsymbol{x}$ you can have $A\boldsymbol{x}-4I\boldsymbol{x}=(A-4I)\boldsymbol{x}=0$ Remember that $M=A-4I$ is a matrix such that $M\boldsymbol{x}=0$. This is a special case your example $Ax=B$. The linear system $M\boldsymbol{x}=0$ has a unique solution iff $\det(M)\neq 0$， that is, $A-4I$ is invertible.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be a bit more specific, we can rewrite the equation $Ax = 4x$ as

$$\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix} | & & | \\ v_1 & \dots & v_n \\ |&&|\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_n\end{bmatrix}}_{Ax} = 4\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_n\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 4x_1 \\ \vdots \\ 4x_n\end{bmatrix}.$$

Here’s a hint as to why the question is True:

If $Ax = 4x$ has a unique solution, then $(A - 4I)x = 0$ has a unique solution. What does this say about the null space of $A-4I$, or the number of pivot columns that $A-4I$ has? How does that relate to invertibility of $A-4I$?